# The Content is not Wraping in <p> tag

Tags: theme-development, the-content

Can you please take a Look at [this page](http://rumioptical.com/new-arrivals/) (please hove over the image to see the paragraph) and let me know why the `the_content()` is jumping out of paragraph tag?

```
  echo '<p style="color:#fff !important; font-size:16px; line-height:18;">'.the_content().'</p>';
```

Here us the whole code

```
    <div class="row">
<?php
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'newArraivalsCPT', 'posts_per_page' => 1000 );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
$thumb_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
$thumb_url_array = wp_get_attachment_image_src($thumb_id, 'thumbnail-size', true);
$thumb_url = $thumb_url_array[0];
   echo '<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">';
echo '<div class="thumbnail text-center demo-3">';
echo '<figure>';
the_post_thumbnail('', array('class' => 'img-responsive', 'href' =>$thumb_url));
//            echo '<img src="images/image1.jpg" alt=""/>';
//            echo '<img src="images/image1.jpg" alt=""/>';
            echo '<figcaption class="text-center">';
?>
            <h3 class=""><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
            <?php
                echo '<p style="color:#fff !important; font-size:16px; line-height:18;">'.the_content().'</p>';
            echo '</figcaption>';
        echo '</figure>';

 echo '<br />';

echo '<p><a href="'.$thumb_url.'" class="btn btn-sm btn-brown group1" title="Rumi Optical" role="button">Large Image</a></p>';
echo '</div>';
echo '</div>';
echo '</div>';
endwhile;

?>
```

[image]

> Here is an image from Chrome console

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `the_content()` prints the content with a `p` tag itself. I mean, if you use

```
echo '<p class="our_p">' . the_content() . '</p>;
```

It actually outputs-

```
<p class="our_p"><p>lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p></p>
```

Use `get_the_content()` instead. It will return the unfiltered content. Something link this-

```
echo '<p class="our_p">' . get_the_content() . '</p>;
```

Codex: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_content

Comment: You've also broken any code that depends on the `the_content` filter, including shortcodes and image imbeds.

Answer (score 2):

First, you can *almost* solve this simply by not trying to concatenate the string.

```
echo '<p style="color:#fff !important; font-size:16px; line-height:18;">',the_content(),'</p>';
```

Notice that I have used commas around `the_content()` instead of periods. `echo` will take a series of comma separated arguments and print them successively.

However, `the_content()` runs formatting filters on the post content so you will end up with nested paragraphs tags, which is bad form.

You can use `get_the_content()` as already suggested in another answer... that is:

```
echo '<p style="color:#fff !important; font-size:16px; line-height:18;">'.get_the_content().'</p>';
```

But ...

> An important difference from the_content() is that get_the_content()
>   does not pass the content through the 'the_content'. This means that
>   get_the_content() will not auto-embed videos or expand shortcodes,
>   among other things.
>
> https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_content

... now embeds and shortcodes don't work, nor do some formatting filters and you've potentially broken some filters added by themes and plugins too. ***This is not a good solution.***

What you probably want is something much less complicated:

```
echo '<div class="figcap-content>';
  the_content();
echo '</div>';
```

Or, if you must cram everything onto one line:

```
echo '<span class="figcap-content>'.the_content().'</span>';
```

Use rules in your stylesheet to format the content, as you should:

```
.figcap-content {
  color:#fff !important; 
  font-size:16px; 
  line-height:18;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**the_content()** function prints the content with a **p** tag itself.
you can use

`<?php echo $post->post_content; ?>`

for geting the post content.It will not add the P tag automatically.